# Ionic *ngIf - Check for global variables

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

Can `*ngIf` only check for local variables of the page or can I check global variables?

I want to do the following:

home.page.html

```html
<div *ngIf="debugService.debugActive"></div>
```

debug.service.ts

```
debugActive: boolean = true;

contructor() {}
...
```

But right now, I have to first initialize the variable on my home.page.ts in order to use it in the html:

home.page.ts

```
import { DebugService } from 'src/app/services/debug.service';

localDebugActive: boolean = false;

constructor(
    private debugService: DebugService,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.localDebugActive = this.debugService.debugActive;
}
```

home.page.html

```html
<div *ngIf="localDebugActive"></div>
```

This means an extra-step and filling my whole pages with local variables. Is it possible without redeclaring it and using it directly in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way:

1. Make a service instance public

   ```js
   constructor(
       public debugService: DebugService,
   ) {}
   ```
2. Use a method (recommended way).

   ```js
   public isDebugActive() {
       return this.debugService.debugActive;
   }

   <div *ngIf="isDebugActive()"></div>
   ```

Comment: Thank you, the method 2 seems more elegant than my way of creating a new variable while still not exposing my debugService as public

Answer (score 1):

The only way a component gets access to a service is by injecting it, ensuring that dependency injection works correctly. Services aren't really **global variables**, as you put it: they're not simply "accessible from anywhere". You do need to use DI.

*Technically* you can inject a service as a `public` variable rather than a `private` one, and access its members directly from the template. This is generally considered code smell, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the injected service as public :

```js
public debugService: DebugService
```

And use it in your template.
Though I don't like that very much, but for simple display, that would do the trick.

Comment: You're not the only one who doesn't like it ^^ it's definitely code smell.

Comment: I know, but sometimes we start with poor solutions but that work, and then we improve :)

Comment: Sure, but when the OP is already using the best practice (at least as far as simple architecture is concerned), shifting to public service variables seems like a step backwards rather than an improvement ^^

Comment: Right, you found the proper words in your answer indeed ! Cheers :)

Comment: Funny idea, but yeah I think it would not be worth it with exposing variables^^

So elsewise it would not be possible?